# Existence of integral, $\int_{[1,\infty)} fd\nu$, with respect to measure, $\nu$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the Borel measure, $\nu$, on $[1,\infty)$ given by
$$\tag{1}
\nu(A):=\int_A \frac{1}{x}d\lambda,
$$
where $\lambda$ is the $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Let $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x):=\cos(x)e^{-x}$. I want to show if the integral
$$\tag{2}
\int_{[1,\infty)} fd\nu
$$
exists. I believe (although I am not sure) that
$$\tag{3}
\int_{[1,\infty)} fd\nu=\int_{[1,\infty)} \frac{1}{x}f\ d\lambda,
$$
The Lebesgue integral of a continuous function is equal to the Riemann integral, so if eq. $(3)$ is correct, then
$$\tag{4}
\int_{[1,\infty)} fd\nu=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}f\ dx.
$$
Every continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, which would then imply that the integral exists. Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with my reasoning here (specifically, if eq. $(3)$ is correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, line (3) is correct; that is, the following associativity formula holds:
$$\int_{[1,\infty )} f d\nu = \int_{[1,\infty)}f\frac{1}{x}d \lambda$$
To show that $f$ is $\nu$-integrable, we may use Hölder's inequality to get:
$$\int_{[1,\infty)} \left| \frac{\cos x}{x} e^{-x} \right| d\lambda \leq \left\| \frac{\cos x}{x} \right\|_\infty \int_{[1,\infty)} e^{-x} dx = e^{-1}< \infty$$
where the $\infty$-norm is readily seen to be $1$ and the integral is computed via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Riemann integrals.

Comment: Great, thank you.